"metadata" is not a valid Next.js entry export value
when I install next.js 14 with typescript it will appear this error which is pointing to my meta data type!
import type { Metadata } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "next app",
  description: "next app 14",

};

it sometime go off when I change my component page but generally I have problem
by the way It does not cause disturbance with dev or build mode! it just an error in vsCode

If you think this is just a VScode error, you can check the TypeScript configuration in VSCode.
Just open VScode and in control panel search for settings.json().
Inside that add
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}

and save the file.
